# The meaning of "to look at the lake"

Tags: expressions, figurative

I can't find it anywhere else as of right now, but I've seen people using this expression several times and I still haven't been able to understand what it means. I tried looking for its meaning on the internet, but all I could find was the literal meaning, not the figurative one. An example can be seen below.

[image]

Comment: It's not a usage with any significant currency, but my guess is it's based on the idea that although the lake *surface* appears calm and still, there's turmoil going on underneath (figuratively, the guy who's happy using SFML + OpenGL himself can't see that other people are wrestling with real problems in this area).

Comment: Perhaps it's meant in the same figurative way as *you're just seeing the tip of the iceberg*.

Answer (score 2):

There is a thread on Reddit from a year ago that asks "[What's up with comments saying 'I am looking at the lake'?](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/izlepd/whats_up_with_comments_saying_i_am_looking_at_the/) The OP writes, in part, as follows:

> I was going through some askreddit threads and saw a comment that was edited to say "i am looking at the lake"
>
> I knew I had seen someone else say this before so I looked it up and found hundreds of comments with this phrase or or "he is looking at the lake", as well as the phrase "he is going to cinema" or "i am going to cinema"
>
> ...
>
> Is this code for something? There is also no comments saying "she is looking at the lake" or "she is going to cinema"

The upshot of the most highly upvoted responses both to this question and to a related one at "[Anyone know what these weird comments mean? 'i am looking at the lake' and 'he is going to cinema'](https://www.reddit.com/r/InternetMysteries/comments/izm4d3/anyone_know_what_these_weird_comments_mean_i_am/)" seems to be that the wording is a script designed to replace original text that a Reddit user posted but now wants to delete, in such a way that if other users try to restore the original wording of the deleted post, all they get is the innocuous "I am looking at the lake" (or something similar) replacement wording instead. The script seems to be specific to Reddit and may in fact be traceable to a browser extension called Nuke Your Reddit.

If this explanation is accurate, there is no independent significance to "you are looking at the lake"; the phrase isn't an idiomatic expression or a secret code message or anything else. It is simply glorified "Lorem ipsum dolor..." dummy text that serves its entire purpose by existing at all, not by conveying any meaning.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that Reddit posts cannot be deleted, but can be edited, thus the solution is to edit a post by creating an innocuous sentence.